# Add class to views row using a template

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm using Views 3 with Drupal 7. I'm trying to dynamically add a class to the "views-row" line of a view based on the node type. I have a view with a relationship which is duplicating items when a relationship exists. I thought by adding a class for the node type into the views-row line I could hide the field in the row. I'm not sure whether I should be overriding views-view-unformatted.tpl.php or views-view-fields.tpl.php, to add the class and how I can extract the node type from the data to add it into the the classes for that line.

I'd be grateful for any guidance.

Ben

Comment: have you tried the distinct option?

Comment: Hi Mohammed, yes, I've already tried the distinct option. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Views itself will tell you which file to use as a template.  Go to the config page for the relevant view and choose *Theme: Information* under **Other**.  This will print out a list of potential templates; the template shown in bold is the one that is in use.

To get the node type, you can use the `dpm()` function of the devel module.  For example, if you have devel enabled, you can simply insert `dpm($row)` in the template file, load a page containing the view in your browser, and then dig through the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Patrick.  I've tried for a couple of hours now without success, but we'll keep trying.

Comment: You need to clear the cache before the template file will be recognized.

Comment: I have cleared the cache and I have my custom template files working okay. The difficulty I'm having is using the correct variable in the template. I'm pretty sure the template I need to change is the views-view-unformatted.tpl.php, but I just can't seem to find the variable I need to add to it. I have been using the dpm function.

Comment: Well, if the template is being read correctly, it will appear in **bold** under *Theme: Information* in the Views UI.  Check that first to make sure you're editing the right template.  (Assuming you're not getting dpm() output-- if you are, there's no reason to do this.)